# Does resonant inductive coupling work in the presence of a strong magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, induction, resonance

Does resonant inductive coupling work in the presence of a strong magnetic field? I am unsure because resonant inductive coupling uses magnetic fields to transmit power wirelessly and a strong magnetic field may cause interference. Example scenario: two devices using RIC in an MRI machine. Will they work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIC involves magnetic fields oscillating at a high frequency. The system won't pick up any other frequency.

A constant-in-time (DC) magnetic field magnetic field has no direct effect because 0 Hz is the wrong frequency, and it has no indirect effect by the superposition principle.

I guess it's possible that there may be a magnetic material in the RIC system (say, an iron-core inductor). I doubt there is, but I don't know for sure. If there is, there could be problems because (1) The DC magnetic field would affect the AC magnetic susceptibility (the superposition principle stops being true with strong fields and magnetic materials), and (2) The component would get ripped out and go flying and damage the MRI :-D

Comment: Thanks, by the way regarding the MRI, that was just an example I don't have any plans of doing such a thing :p